# If $T = \langle t \rangle$ for an involution $t$, $M$ the normal closure of $T$, and $U \cap M \ne 1$. Then $T^M = T^G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group with subgroup $U \le G$ of odd order such that $U\ne U^g$ implies $U\cap U^g = 1$. Suppose there exists an involution $t \notin U$ such that $N_G(U) = TU$ with $T = \langle t \rangle$ (and hence $U$ has index two in its normalizer).

Then I know that if $C_U(t) \ne 1$, then $C_U(t)T/T$ is a Frobenius complement in $C_G(t)/T$.

> Let $M$ be the normal closure of $T$, if $M \cap U \ne 1$, then by the above mentioned fact the conjugates of $t$ in $M$ are the same as those in $G$ and $t$ does not centralize $(M\cap U)/(M\cap U)'$.

The first statement says, that if $g = t^x$ for some $x \in G$, then we find some $m \in M$ such that $g = t^m$. As $M$ is normal, $g = t^x$ forces $g \in M$. But how to choose that $m \in M$? For the second statement, that $t$ centralizes $(M\cap U)/(M\cap U)'$ is equivalent with $[u,t] \in (M\cap U)'$ for all $u \in M\cap U$, so we have to show that $[u, t]$ could not be a product of commutators with elements from $M \cap U$. I do not see how to achieve this, but I also do not see the connection to the mentioned fact? I hope you can help me!

Comment: You have $G=UM$ by an earlier question.

Comment: @DerekHolt But this just gives that $x = um \in UM$, hence $t^x = t^{um}$, but we still need to get rid of the $u$ in the exponent?

Comment: Yes that's right, you do!  Remember that $t$ normalizes $U$ and $|U|$ is odd.

Comment: @DerekHolt Set $k = |U|$, then $(t^x)^k = (t^k)^x = t^x$, but on the other side $(t^{um})^k = ((t^u)^k)^m = (t^k u')^m = (tu')^m = t^m u'^m = t^m u' m'$. So $t^x = t^m u' m'$ for some $u' \in U, m' \in M$, am I on the right track? Is there some further "trick" which gives $u'm' = 1$?

Comment: $t$ and $t^u$ are conugate in $\langle t, t^u \rangle \le M$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Okay, with some "high-level" arguments without computation: Set $r := tt^u = [t,u] \le U$, then $\langle t, t^u \rangle$ is a didedral group of order $2|r|$, where $|r|$ is odd. Hence the reflections (as Sylow subgroups) are all conjugate, in particular $t$ and $t^u$. Was that the same reasoning you had in mind? And for the 2nd question that $t$ does not centralize $(M\cap U)/(M\cap U)'$, with the above $[t,u]$ is in the commutator subgroup of the dihedral group, which lies in $(M\cap U)'$, but they say it does *not* centralize $(M\cap  U)/(M\cap U)'$, so whats wrong here?

Comment: Update on my last comment. The dihedral group lies in $M$ and $[t,u]$ is in its commutator subgroup, hence $[t,u] \in M'$ Also of course $(M\cap U)' \le M'$. But it is not the case that $[t,u]$ must be in $(M\cap U)'$, as $t \notin U$ and $u$ need not be in $M$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is closely related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1611205/let-n-be-maximal-normal-subgroup-with-tu-cap-n-1-where-tu-n-gu-th) of mine. As written there, the arguments are related to a paper. I rephrase the relevant lemma from there, the assumption about $U \le G$ is as stated in the question (they call such suchgroups $T$-subgroups in the paper). The relevant Theorem of the paper is Theorem 5. I append a much more detailed proof, explaining all points which were unclear to me a few weeks before.

*Lemma 1.* If $N \unlhd G$ and $N \cap U$, then

(a) $G = TUN$

(b) if $t \notin N$, then $UN$ is a Frobenius group with $U$ as complement, and $TU$ has a normal complement in $G$;

(c) if $t \in N$, then $t$ centralizes $U/(U\cap N)$, and $U \cap N$ is a $T$-subgroup of $N$.

*Lemma 2.* If $N \unlhd G$ and $N \cap U = 1$, then

(a) if $t \notin N$, then $UN$ is a Frobenius group with kernel $N$ and complement $U$, and $UN/N$ is a $T$-subgroup of $G/N$;

(b) if $t \in N$, then $U$ has a normal complement in $G$.

*Lemma 3.* If $C_U(t) \ne 1$, then $C_U(T)T/T$ is a Frobenius complement in $C_G(t)/T$.

*Lemma 4.* If $t$ centralizes $U/U'$, then there is a characteristic subgroup $M$ of $G$ intersecting $U$ in $U'$ and containing $t$. If $t$ does not centralize $U/U'$, then there is a characteristic subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that $N \cap TU = 1$ and $N$ contains all involutions not conjugate to $t$.

With these lemmata we are going to proof.

*Theorem 5.* One of the following holds.

(a) $U$ has a normal complement.

(b) $TU$ has a normal complement.

(c) $G$ has two normal subgroups $N < M < G$, such that $G/M \cong U/(U\cap M)$, $N \cap TU = 1$, and $M/N$ is a simple group with $(U\cap M)N/N$ is a $T$-subgroup and only one class of involutions.

*Proof.* Let $M$ be the normal closure of $T$. If $M \cap U = 1$ then as $[t,u] \le M \cap U = 1$ we have that $t$ centralizes $U$ and with Lemma 2 (b) $U$ has a normal complement in $G$. If $M \cap U \ne 1$, then as $\langle t^g, t\rangle \le M$ generated a dihedral group, and as the product of both involutions $[t,u] \in M\cap U$ has odd order, this dihedral group has order $2m$ with $m$ odd, which gives that both involutions are conjugate in $M$. For that argument that $t$ does not centralize $(U\cap M)/(U\cap M)'$ I guess the citation of Lemma 3 is an error, at least I do not see what it has to do with Lemma 3. I do it with Lemma 4. To apply it restrict to $M$ and look at $M\cap U$ in $M$. If $g \in N_G(M \cap U)$ as $M \cap U\ne 1$ this implies $g \in N_G(U)$, and as $M \unlhd G$ the other inclusion is obvious, hence $N_G(M\cap U) = N_G(U)$ and
$N_G(U\cap M) \cap M = N_G(U) \cap M = TU \cap M = T(U\cap M)$, where the last equation follows by the Dedekind identity. Also if $1 \ne U\cap M \cap (U\cap M)^g \le U \cap U^g$, then $U = U^g$, hence also $U\cap M = (U\cap M)^g$, so that $U\cap M$ is a $T$-subgoup in $M$. Now Lemma 4 gives that if $t$ centralizes $U\cap M / (U \cap M)'$ that there exists some characteristic subgroup $K$ of $M$ such that $U \cap M \cap K =  (U \cap M)'$. Then $K \unlhd G$ and $t \in K$, which gives $K = M$ by definition of $M$ so that $U \cap M = (U\cap M)'$, but by Feit and Thompson $(U\cap M)' \ne U \cap M)$ (this is mentioned in the paper on page 284, but I do not see if there is any simpler argument possible). Hence $t$ does not centralizes $(M\cap U)/(M\cap U)'$. Hence also by Lemma 4 there exists a normal subgroup $\hat N$ such that $\hat N \cap TU = 1$ and $\hat N$ contains all involutions not conjugate to $t$. Now choose $N$ maximal with $N \cap TU = 1$, then $\hat N \le N$ and hence $N$ contains all involutions not conjugate to $t$. By Lemma 2 (a) $UN$ is a Frobenius group with kernel $N$, hence nilpotent. Applying Lemma 2 (a) on the $T$-subgroup $U \cap M$ in $M$. But here I do not see that $N \le M$, by Lemma 4 $\hat N \le M$ is guaranted, and as I see it the maximiality property is not used. So set $\hat N = N$ for the following (or was maximal normal in $M$ meant?) and apply Lemma 2 (a) on $N\unlhd M$ and $U\cap M$ in $M$, which gives that $(U\cap M)N/N$ is a $T$-subgroup in $M/N$. Assume we have $N \le K \unlhd M$ such that $K / N$ is disjoint from $(U\cap M)N/N$, then $K \cap U\cap M \le N$ and $M = (U\cap M)K$ and further with Lemma 1 (a) $G = UM = U(U\cap M)K = UK$. But we also have $K\cap U\cap M \le N \cap (U\cap M) = 1$, and so by $K \le M$ we got $K \cap U = (K\cap M) \cap U = 1$, hence $K$ is a normal complement to $U$ in $G$ and this is part (a) of the Theorem. Hence we can assume that $MN$ has no normal subgroup disjoint from $(U\cap M)N/N$. Now suppose we have $N \le K \unlhd M$ with $K\cap (U\cap M) > N$ and $t \notin K$. Then we can apply Lemma 1 on $M$ and $U\cap M$ and find that $T(U\cap M)$ has a complement $\hat K$ in $M$. Also as $\hat K \le M$ and $TU\cap M = T(U\cap M)$ by Dedekind we have $\hat K \cap TU = \hat K \cap M \cap TU = \hat K \cap (M\cap U)T = 1$ and by Lemma 1 (a) $G = MU = \hat KT(U\cap M)U = \hat K TU$, hence $TU$ has a normal complement in $G$ and this is case (b) of the Theorem. Hence we can assume that every normal subgroup with the above conditions contains $t$. But as $M$ is the normal closure this gives that $M/N$ is simple. Now assume $M/N$ where nilpotent, then is must be a $p$-group as the Sylow subgroups are normal (and it must have prime power order by properties of $p$-groups). But $t \in M$ and $t \notin N$, so that $M/N$ must be a $2$-group and simple means it must have exactly order $2$, hence $M = T$, but $M\cap U \ne 1$ by assumption, so this is not possible and $M/N$ could not be nilpotent. Now suppose $K$ is another subgroup with the same properties as $N$, then $KN \le N$ or $KN = M$, the first gives $K \le N$, so if we choosed $N$ and $K$ maximal in $N$ this would give $K = N$. In the second case we have
$$
 M / N \cong K / (K\cap N)
$$
and hence would be nilpotent as a factor group of the nilpotent group $K$ (here the paper says isomorphic to a subgroup, but I guess this is an error). So this gives that $N$ is uniquely specified and characteristic, hence normal in $G$.